# php doesn't recognize numeric parameters as number on mac when typed using local language

Tags: php, laravel, fonts

I'm trying to validate some `ajax` request parameters using `php` , it works fine on Windows. 
On MAC when I type a number with English keyboard it works fine , but when I switch to local language other than English, `php` doesn't recognize numeric values as number and I get a validation error.

I wrote this simple code to check if `php` considers the param as number:

```
echo is_numeric($request->input('mobile')) ? 'yes' : 'no' ;
```

It always return `no` when I type in the input with local language (Persian). Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: The mystery of the Persian php parser

Comment: Have you inspected the value of `$request->input('mobile')`? Try `var_dump($request->input('mobile'))` things like whitespace, for example, could affect the output of `is_numeric()`. Also, don't use `is_numeric()`. Use [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype-digit) instead.

Comment: @Sherif yeah , there's no extra character ,  but it shows them with a local font which i assume is the reason for not accepting them as number

Comment: Fonts really have no place in this equation. What you're looking for are non-printable or white-space characters that might effect the result. This can include anything from a NUL byte to a SPACE or NON-BREAKING-SPACE character. The reason I suggest to use `var_dump()` to inspect that is because `var_dump()` doesn't just display the value, it also tells you the length (*in bytes*) of the string. So for example `var_dump("123\0\0\0")` gives you `string(6) "123"` note the `6` there. It's very important in debugging this. To get to the invisible characters use `bin2hex("123\0\0\0")` for hex rep